# How to add product collection?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, product-collection, category-products

I was using Magento 1.7 but updated to 2.0 and now this is not working...

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="5" category_id="39" template="catalog/product/list2.phtml"}}
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For magento2 you need to use **class** in your block while calling instead of **type**. Also the **syntax** of calling is changed.

Try **below code:**

```
{{block class="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" category_id="4" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml"}}
```

Here **Magento** is vendor and **Catalog** is your module. so you need to call template with **Magento:Catalog**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below code

```
 {{block class="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" category_id="39" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml"}}
```